# Find control position on canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, frameworkelement

I have a `Canvas` which contains a few `Textblocks` and I need to find the top and left corner points that were assigned in the XAML Document. How can I get those two properties?

When I loop through the Framework Elements on the `Canvas` I can't seem to find those to properties listed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here some examples how to get the values:

```
foreach(FrameworkElement fe in canvas.Children){

   // example 0
   double top=(double)fe.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
   double left=(double)fe.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);

   // example 1
   double top1=Canvas.GetTop(fe);
   double left1=Canvas.GetLeft(fe);

}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top.aspx
for more information

Comment: This should actually be double top = Canvas.GetTop(fe);

Comment: Uups, better test before post tired:) Thanks for the info and the acceept. Have changed the examples. Gave you +1 for the question.

Answer (score -2):

### Elegant solution

```
foreach (FrameworkElement fe in Canvas.Children)
         Thickness margin = fe.Margin;

MessageBox.Show("Left: " + margin.Left + "Top: " + margin.Top);
```