# How to highlight a row on a Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas

My Wpf form has a Search box and a Canvas.

Onload my Canvas is rendered with Rows of data, with each row has: Username and Age details
I perform a successful search then corresponding row in the canvas needs to be highlighted.

Please provide some pointers

Comment: Please provide some code samples so that we can see what you attempted so far to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am trying to implement it on an existing complex system; I will extract required part and upload it here. Thanks

Comment: I was able to achieve it.

Step 1: Loop thru' elements on canvas and locate your element.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313277/find-control-position-on-canvas)

Step2:  As we got the element, we can paint it (I am working on this.)

Comment: Update : 

To paint text on a element I have used Foreground property. 

<element>.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

Comment: Really, please consider providing more information in the question. And then put your findings in an answer to document your breakthrough.